# Is there a free backup utility for PC that can be loaded onto a Mac? (For backing up photos and music)

Tags: mac, backup

I was wondering if there was some sort of free software where I can run a backup utility on my PC and load the files onto my Mac without having to manually copy all the files myself?

Comment: Is the PC and Mac on the same Local Network?

Comment: @Luke Probably, but I can't say for sure and anyway this is for a friend and I don't think she'd know how to network them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick: http://www.aerofs.com/

Free software to automatically sync collections of files on different computers. It's peer-to-peer and works both when the computers on the same LAN (very fast) or even across the internet. They have a version for PC and Mac, so just download the appropriate one on each computer, define the directories you want to sync/backup and you're in business.

Good luck,
yosh